# couchbase spark connector DCP recover from last position

Tags: apache-spark, couchbase

I have this spark application:

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
                           .setAppName("StreamingSample")
                           .set("com.couchbase.bucket.test", "")
                           .set("com.couchbase.nodes", "test-machine")
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

 ssc.couchbaseStream(from = FromNow, to = ToInfinity)
    .filter(!_.isInstanceOf[Snapshot]) // Don't print snapshots, just mutations and deletions
    .checkpoint(Seconds(2))
    .foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val om: Broadcast[ObjectMapper] = ScalaObjectMapper.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)

  rdd.foreach {
    case m: Mutation =>

      val content: Map[String, Object] = om.value.readValue(m.content, classOf[Map[String, Object]])

      content("objectType") match {
        case "o" => println("o")
        case "c" => println("c")
        case "s" => println("s")
        case unsupportedType => println("unsupported")
      }


    case m: Deletion => println("delete")
  }

})
```

when recover spark fail how I recover from last position?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is you're asking a bit more?

Comment: let say the app is running for 2 days, and then failed and loads again after 5 minutes. how I will get all the changes of the missing 5 minutes? I what to start getting changes from the last position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current connector version (1.2.1) can only stream either from the beginning or from the current position (end of the stream). So in your example, you have no choice but to change `FromNow` to `FromBeginning` and then skip (in code) past all the messages you've already seen until you catch up.

The client team is currently working on a new implementation that will be able to remember state, so you'll be able to restore from a specific point in the stream.

Comment: Do I have other option from scala or java code to read all changes with recovery from last point?

Comment: Another Question is how can I know if I already saw a message?

Comment: You could connect directly to the raw DCP stream, in which case you can actually specify the sequence number from which to stream. However, this is not officially supported, so it's at your own risk. A generic DCP client is currently in the works, and that will support resuming from a specific point, etc. It's likely that the future versions of the Spark connectors will use this client as well. I don't have any sort of timeline to share on that, though, I'm sorry.

Comment: You can track which messages you've seen by looking at Snapshot DCP messages, which you're actually filtering out in your code example above. Every so often, DCP sends a snapshot message per vBucket (== shard) with the sequence number that was most recently sent to you. Note that sequence numbers are per-vBucket, so normally you have 1024 separate sub-streams to track.